# is it possible to reset innodb_row_lock without restart MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, innodb

Now I could using this command to check the innodb_row_lock values:

```
show status like 'innodb_row_lock%';



Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   4
Innodb_row_lock_time    22471927
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    52
Innodb_row_lock_time_max    22327
Innodb_row_lock_waits   426696
```

is it possible to reset the data without restart database? I aready searching from internet but no one talks about this.

Comment: you'd need to [gdb batch change](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/03/23/too-many-connections-no-problem/) a [significant array of variables](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/include/srv0srv.h#L71). Its better to have monitoring that looks at differential values over time and ignores global avg/max variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The workaround:

1. `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'Innodb_row_lock%';`
2. Run your query/queries
3. `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'Innodb_row_lock%';`
4. Programmatically subtract the values.  (Well, perhaps only Innodb_row_lock_waits can really be subtracted.)

It may be possible to use `information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS`, but (in some cases) you get hit by the 'Uncertainty principle'.

In my experience, these values are "typical":
Innodb_row_lock_current_waits  -- rarely more than 0
Innodb_row_lock_time  --  non interesting
Innodb_row_lock_time_avg  --  Usually 10-1000ms
Innodb_row_lock_time_max  --  Usually < 50K (ms)
Innodb_row_lock_waits  --  not useful, except in your case of "subtracting"

Where are you hoping to take this inquiry?

If you would like a review of your variables and status:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning